# Почему деление на слоги делается по принципу восходящей звучности?

Tags: фонетика, слоги

Слог определяется как произносительный квант речи и характеризуется акустической или артикуляционной слитностью звуков при их произношении. По одной теории, слог – это один гласный звук или несколько звуков, которые произносятся одним толчком выдыхаемого воздуха (лод-ка). По другой теории, слоги строятся по принципу восходящей звучности (ло-дка).  Деление на слоги лод-ка кажется более естественным (не надо думать о звучности) – кажется, раньше применялось именно эта теория. А чем объясняется переход к теории звучности?

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ
При делении слов на слоги по методу восходящей звучности предлагаются специальные правила (5 правил). Их нужно просто выучить, или они имеют какое-нибудь обоснование? Кстати, эта «восходящая звучность» не всегда соблюдается, например: пар-та. Здесь сонорный следует после более звучного гласного. Это как-то объясняется?

Answer (score 3):

Да, это акустический и артикуляторный подходы к слогу Щербы и Аванесова.Но наука не стоит на месте, их теории привели к мысли об УСЛОВНОСТИ разделения на слоги.Сейчас фонетика ушла далеко вперёд, доказано, что тенденция к восходящей звучности была уже в древнерусском,она  есть частный случай универсального принципа восходяще-нисходящей звучности, который остаётся одним из принципов построения слога и СРЯ. Проведены  (в 70-80-е годы)экспериментально-фонетические исследования слога как произносительной единицы . На них основана современная наука фонетика и фонология.(Учения о фонеме,разработана фонематическая транскрипция)
http://www.speech.nw.ru/Manual/glava8.htm

Вот здесь есть интересное по теме:
http://gumfak.ru/russ_html/rus_konspekt/kon1.shtml

Comment: Теория звучности хороша в высшей школе - там же, где до сих пор находится фонема. Там наука - исторические исследования,современные теории, все это интересно и нужно профессиональным ученым. А как это соотносится со школой, должны ли в этом разбираться маленькие и взрослые дети?

Comment: Их же не заставляют разбираться в подробностях, просто говорят о том, что есть такая теория, соответствующая реальным законам в языке,и учат делить на слоги в соответствии с ней. Мы же не будем сейчас делить на слоги по Ломоносову? Его вклад достоин восхищения в те времена, но сейчас сведения устарели. Всё верно: наука идёт вперёд, мы должны успевать осваивать новые сведения. Для меня фонология тоже трудна, я окончила школу в 1971 году, её ещё не было, но потихоньку пытаюсь освоить, когда студенты-выпускники обращаются, они же считают, что их умная учительница всё знает

Comment: Думаю, что трудности часто создаются для того, чтобы их успешно преодолевать. Эта теория звучности уместна в качестве упражнения для студентов-первокурсников, в остальном она ничего не  дает, только время тратится зря. Какая от нее практическая польза школьникам? Раньше по слогам учились читать, а по этим слогам чему можно научиться? Чем устарел Ломоносов и в чем тут движение вперед?
Разбивка "лод-ка" естественна, это структура реальных слов. А вот слог "ДКА" с двумя смычными согласными и выговорить-то сложно.

Comment: Лод-ка было естественно, когда мы учили по слогам читать своих детей, а теперь за это ругают,нет плавности. Теперь учат читать по другой методике,петь слоги, вырабатывают плавность, и это даёт бОльшие успехи, а когда по старинке - путает детей. Просто Вы привыкли, наше поколение консервативно, но это не говорит о том,, что мы правы.

Comment: Мне на индивидуальных занятиях приходилось разных детей учить - в том числе десятилетних, причем требовался гарантированный результат в ограниченные сроки. Думаю, что лучший способ обучения - это по слоговым схемам - слитные слоги и отдельно стоящие согласные и гласные. Ло-дка здесь точно не поможет.

Comment: Ну, это Вы так думаете, ещё как поможет. Мне пришлось немного поработать в методкабинете гороно, была на многих уроках в начальных классах. Сейчас очень хорошие развивающие методики,по сравнению со старыми - просто класс. Фонетику дети понимают легко.Иногда взрослые не понимают (кто по старым методикам учился - это мешает), внучка у меня есть в 3 классе - только так шпарит.Просто Вам попался такой ученик.У меня тоже разные попадаются, приходится на пальцах объяснять, но новые методики помогают здорово.

Comment: -дка  что-то  не  поётся.  Может  к  закону  открытого  слога  вернёмся,  усилим  редуцированные,  и  будем  петь  слоги.

Comment: Простите,но поются гласные:[лооооо-ткааааа]. Как раз по закону открытого слога. А не поётся у Вас, потому что вы пытаетесь произнести без ассимиляции по глухости -дт, не получится, нужно соблюдать фонетические законы. Дети знают об оглушении и озвончении.

Comment: Закрытые  слоги  только  в  конце  слова  что-ли ?

Answer (score 0):

Все верно, слог "ДКА" произнести сложно, так как по всем правилам Вы должны произнести "ТКА". Звонкий согласный перед глухим произносится глухо ,правило восходящей звучности соблюдается. Кстати, я не согласна, что разбивка  лод-ка естественна. Попробуйте проскандировать , как на стадионе. Заметите, что получится ло-дка, де-во-чка, мо-крый, кар-та(согласно принципу восходящей звучности сонорный не может стоять перед глухим согласным, поэтому отходит к предыдущему слогу).